# Does next js implement a maximum cache size with an invalidation algorithm such as LRU?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have a next js site that uses getServerSideProps. I would like to use getStaticProps and incremental static regeneration (ISR) instead for the performance advantages.  My current memory use is about 125MB. Crawling all of the pages when using getStaticProps results in using around 2G of memory. I would like to fit the pages into 500Mb but I don't see anyway to set an upper limit on the cache used by getStaticProps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set and tweak with the `isrMemoryCacheSize` parameter in `next.config.js` and define how much memory you want to use for the inMemory cache.

Just keep in check that this is a rather recent feature that's not very well documented. The only hint you can tweak this setting is located here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#self-hosting-isr

Answer (score 1):

As of Next.js v14.1.0, the configuration option `isrMemoryCacheSize` has been deprecated in favour of `cacheMaxMemorySize`.

```js
module.exports = {
  cacheMaxMemorySize: 0, // set to zero will disable default in-memory caching
}
```

Documentation of this feature can be found here:
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying#configuring-caching